# Append after read_pickle

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I'm trying to open a pickle file, append it, and write it back out as a new save file, but when I open it later, it is always the same file. How do I append properly?

My code:

```
OGFile = pd.read_pickle(file,compression=None)
OGFile.append(data)
OGFile.to_pickle(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second line should be:

```
OGFile = OGFile.append(data)
```

The `append()` method doesn't change the DataFrame object 'inplace'.